# Connecting my login system to my likes and dislikes system

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I am very new to to the whole web developing thing. However, I have a very common website I'm creating to promote my music.

I already have a login system and a like/dislike system. The problem I'm having is when I have a dummy user login, I cannot rate the like or dislike items. When I created the like/dislike feature, I didnt incorporate the login system because at the time I didn't know how.

In addition to this, I would like to know how to have the member name show even if they post on my blogs within my website. Can anyone please offer some advice to my problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Break this up into a few different questions. You'll also need to post your code

Comment: first have a look at sessions if logged in user like or dislike store user id in like dislike table and when a non registered member like or dislikes add random number in userid coloumn in your like dislike table

Answer (score 0):

When you click "like" or "dislike," you must call an AJAX function to check whether or not the user is logged in.  The results of which, would be shown in a pop-up DIV.  Please let me know if you would like a demonstration.  Thanks.

Comment: @webarto:  What's wrong with that?  Youtube.com has a similar function.

Comment: without ajax you can do this also

Comment: @dianuj:  Yes, but AJAX is a popular way of solving the problem.